# How do I change textbox size using css? And how do I connect my css file with my html file

Tags: html, css

I want to change my textbox size using HTML, for now I only have this as my

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Enter your question:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="myquestion" placeholder="Your question here"><br>
    <button type="button" id="mybutton">Submit</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, how do I connect my css file with my HTML file? my css file name is style.css
Second, how do I change `<input type="text" id="myquestion" placeholder="Your question here"><br>` size using css? I kinda wanna at least use css because for now I know nothing about css. It'll be really good if you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your CSS file in your HTML page by adding the following line within the `<head>` tag:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

When you say you want to change the size of the input, I assume you mean you want to change its width. You can do this using:

```css
#myquestion {
  width: 400px;
}
```

---

To learn about HTML and CSS, I highly recommend going through [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: It worked but the text will be at the center I tried doing start but it's still at the center and at the left. Please help me fix this